# Can someone debug my script?

Tags: javascript, debugging, service, binary, translate

This is my code. it is supposed to translate text to binary and back. It tells me the word response isnt defined and the function asktocode and asktodecode arent either. help would be much appreciated. ( : 
This is great. i even included that button idea to make it more user friendly.
thanks. 
   -Luke
It wants me to add more words so I guess i have to.

```
function texttobin(code) {
var A = 01000001                                    
var B = 01000010
var C = 01000011
var D = 01000100
var E = 01000101
var F = 01000110
var G = 01000111
var H = 01001000
var I = 01001001
var J = 01001010
var K = 01001011
var L = 01001100
var M = 01001101
var N = 01001110
var O = 01001111
var P = 01010000
var Q = 01010001
var R = 01010010
var S = 01010011
var T = 01010100
var U = 01010101
var V = 01010110
var W = 01010111
var X = 01011000
var Y = 01011001
var Z = 01011010
var a = 01100001
var b = 01100010
var c = 01100011
var d = 01100100
var e = 01100101
var f = 01100110
var g = 01100111
var h = 01101000
var i = 01101001
var j = 01101010
var k = 01101011                              
var l = 01101100
var m = 01101101
var n = 01101110
var o = 01101111
var p = 01110000
var q = 01110001
var r = 01110010
var s = 01110011
var t = 01110100
var u = 01110101
var v = 01110110
var w = 01110111
var x = 01111000
var y = 01111001
var z = 01111010
var comma = 00101110
var period = 00110010
var one = 00110011
var two = 00110101
var three = 00110111
var four = 00111000
var five = 00111001
var six = 00110000
var seven = 00110111   
var eight = 00111000
var nine = 00111001
var zero = 00110000
var spacebar = 00100000 
var asktocode; "Translate text into binary"
// Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

// Process the user's response.
if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
} else {
Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
}
function bintotext (translate) { 
var asktodecode; "Translate binary into text"
}






}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where you're going with that code, but converting text to binary and back is pretty simple:

```
var text = "A";
// character to binary (result: "1000001")
var bin = text.charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
// binary back to character (result: "A")
var char = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bin, 2));
```